# Javascript - why isn't my array loop working?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects (`data`), I am doing this:

`for (var i = 0; data.length < i; i++) {...}`

But it doesn't work. When I use this:

`for (var i in data) {`

It works, but is looping three times, when there is only one object, in this case `i` is: `0` (correct), `indexOfObject` (wtf), `removeItem` (wtf).

Why my first expression is not working? What are those two werid `i` values? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**: Since this thing is a bit complicated, the best I can do is provide a screenshot of my data object: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yQ3T.jpg)

Comment: You'll have to post the actual array value in order for people to provide a complete, accurate answer.

Comment: `for...in` iterates over all enumerable properties of an object. `data` seems to be an *array-like* object, not a normal array and appears to have the properties `indexOfObject` and `removeItem`.

Comment: can you put up fiddle?

Comment: Looks like your `data` is not an array, but an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `for` loop statement, the condition of the loop (`data.length < i`) is the other way round and probably never fulfilled.

It should be:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length;  i++)
   {
      // Now write your code 
   }
```

Comment: Bingo. I didn't see that error. Thank you. :)

Comment: Sorry for just hijacking your post, but I felt pointing out the mistake explicitly is more helpful.

Comment: ohh @FelixKling no problem. I was just doing that. btw thank for edit :)

Comment: I guess sometimes I'm over-ambitious ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you really have an **array** —

```
var a = ["hello", "world"];
```

or

```
var a = new Array();
a[0] = "hello";
a[1] = "world";
```

Then your first loop (with the index variable) is correct.  You should use the `in` style `for` loop for iterating over properties of objects, but the indexed style for the numerically indexed properties of an array.

*edit* — oops good call @Sachin - your `for` loop test is backwards.

If you have a plain object and you want to iterate through its properties, but skip properties found on the object's prototype chain, you can do something like this:

```
for (var name in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    var value = obj[name];
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see from the above given code, you have given wrong condition inside the for loop. First, you are initializing the variable i to 0, and then checking data.length<0. Can any length value be less than zero??

you can use it like:-

```
  for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {...}
```

Try it will work.

Comment: *"Can any length value be less than zero?"* Since this is not a normal array, it actually can. It would not make sense, but it is technically possible.